# Result not set into a variables and session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to store a result of a candidate but it will return a 0; nothing else, and it will always increment the value of cot if value if arraylist are match or not match but it will increase the value of cot.

Please help me - thanks in advance

```
public void get_result()
{
    int cot = 0, inc = 0;float final_result=0;
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

    string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("(select correct from quiz_question)", con);

    con.Open();

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    for (int j = 0; dr.Read(); j++)
    {
        inc++;
        string ans = dr[0].ToString();
        arr.Add(ans);
        Response.Write(arr.ToString());
    }

    ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
    arr1 = (ArrayList)Session["correct_ans"];

    for(int l = 0; l < inc; l++)
    {
        if(arr[l]!=arr1[l])
        {
            cot++;
        }
    }

    Session["result"] = (Double)((cot/100)*100);

    //final_result = ((cot) / 100);
    //final_result = final_result * 100;
    //Session["result"] = (float)final_result;
    //Response.Write(final_result);
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? What is your observation there?

Comment: yes i debug but if i use result variable so after that it will give 0.

Comment: `for (int j = 0` loop is executing? `for(int l = 0;` loop is executing ? What value you are getting in `are` and `arr1`? `if(arr[l]!=arr1[l])` gets executed? What value you get in `cot`? That's what you observe and see if values are as per your logic.